# Where does Scratch saves temporary files?

Tags: files, code

I've set Scratch to show a welcome screen every time I open it so it doesn't show what I was doing previously.

However, I just accidentally closed it and lost something I didn't save that I want to recover. I've read somewhere that Scratch makes backups of unsaved files somewhere. So my question is, where can I find those backups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scratch saves temporary files at `~/.local/share/scratch-text-editor/unsaved/`

Comment: how can I find ~/.local/share/scratch-text-editor/unsaved/ on Windows 10?